# Bones symmetrize the wrong way?

Tags: mesh, objects, armature, bones, mirror

So I made this left side of the rig and I want to symmetrize it to the other side but I get this result? I've been trying to fix it but couldn't get it to work. Some help would be amazing!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symmetry operation will happen on the armature's local X axis, but you probably rotated it 90° on its Z axis in *Object* mode, so the local X axis is not aligned with the global orientation any more. So cancel the symmetry, apply the rotation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) and symmetrize again.

Comment: Thanks this worked! I did not rotate it though so I don't know why this happened, also when I just put it to 90, nothing happend to the rig but symmetrize now works for some reason, weird. But thanks